# Absolutely positioned HTML element on top of anchor that does not prevent clicking on the anchor?

Tags: html, css, anchor, css-position

I am customizing an audio player - http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-01/. What I have done is expanded the play progress bar to be a bit bigger in order to have the title of the currently playing track displayed inside it.

That all worked fine, I have an absolutely positioned element containing the title sitting nicely inside the progress bar. But when I click inside the bar to scan through the song the title element gets in the way and prevents clicking on the bar.

So yeah, I'm trying to find a way to display an element on top of an anchor without it getting in the way of clicking on the anchor. Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: so, during the playback does the progress bar cover the title? or does the title sit on top the entire time? Do you have a sample we can look at?

Answer (score 0):

You can position some element or pseudo-element from the link above the title, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/TteeJ/, with `z-index` bigger than one that title have.

But the link mustn't have any `position` other than `static`, or the `z-index` won't work.

Comment: Thanks for your response kizu! I went to have another play around with it and it appeared to have magically fixed itself... not sure how that happened I must have tweaked some css that indirectly fixed it :)